# How to deselect an ant design tab while still displaying its content?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, antd

I'm wondering if there's a way to deselect a tab in ant design v4 while still displaying the contents of that tab. I've tried setting the `activeKey` prop to `undefined`, which does correctly deselect the tab, but it also hides the content view.

https://4x.ant.design/components/tabs/#API